# Custom XPath rules for XML not working in SonarQube 5.1

Tags: xpath, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 5.1 with sonar-xml-plugin-1.2 for analysis of XML based code. 
I am trying to implement custom rules (XPath) through SonarQube Dashboard using XPath rule > Create.
The Custom XPath rules are getting created and are visible on the Dashboard and are in activated state but are not getting fired during analysis. I don't see any errors in the logs. However, the inbuilt rules are working fine.
Need help with getting custom rules to work.
Thanks

Comment: Please read this and improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

We are also using using SonarQube 5.1 with sonar-xml-plugin-1.2 for analysis of XML based code and it is working fine without any problem. We have written many xpath rule and run against xml file and it shows the violation on sonar dashboard.Pls review your log, check your sonar.properties.

Comment: Hi Jitendra, Thanks for your response, could you please share your sonar.properties file and one sample XPATH rule. Thanks